# Sql Partial Filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sql table look like this

```
Slno   HeadName    Bankcode
1      Abc         Cash
2      Contra      Bank1
3      Contra      Cash 
4      Xyz         Cash
5      Contra      Bank2
6      Contra      Cash
7      Pqr         Bank1
```

My requirement is to filter the table.i Need to remove the 'Contra' from HeadName and BankCode not equal='Cash'
ex. remove slno no 2,5
all other rows I would like to retrive

My table structure and sample data is given below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sampletable2](
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY ,
    [HeadName] [nvarchar](50),
    [BankCode] [nvarchar](50)
)



Insert Into sampletable2 Values(1,'Abc','Cash'),
Insert Into sampletable2 Values(2,'Contra','Bank1')
Insert Into sampletable2 Values(3,'Contra','Cash')
Insert Into sampletable2 Values(4,'Xyz','Cash')
Insert Into sampletable2 Values(5,'Contra','Bank2')
Insert Into sampletable2 Values(6,'Contra','Cash')
Insert Into sampletable2 Values(7,'Pqr' ,'Bank1')

Select * from sampletable2
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
UPDATE sampletable2
SET HeadName = ''
WHERE Headname = 'Contra' AND BankCode != 'Cash'
```

Or delete the Datarow:

```
DELETE FROM sampletable2 
WHERE Headname = 'Contra' AND BankCode != 'Cash'
```

-> will delete Datarow 2 and 5